# Programmatic way to ensure color accuracy on 'AMOLED cinema' or 'Dynamic' screen mode (Android)

Tags: android

Modern smartphones come with various screen modes, whereby colors are displayed differently.

On one end of the spectrum, we have `basic`, where colors are displayed as accurately as possible. On the other end, we have `AMOLED cinema` (`Dynamic` in older devices), where all colors are richly saturated.

I'm developing a web forum for mobile, where the background colors appear *too-vivid-to-read* in `AMOLED  cinema` display setting.

Is there any programmatic way available that could allow me to have accurate colors all around, regardless what display setting a user picks?

If not, what's my second best option? Testing a color in various mobile screens and making peace with all the variations it shows up as? I'd like to know how industry experts handle these situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's no programmatic way to handle this. I'll just have to finalize color values that are digestible across various displays.